# Google Fonts are not rendering on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-webfonts

I'm building a new WordPress theme (don't know if that's relevant) and there's this issue that keeps bugging me.

I've loaded up Roboto Slab from Google Webfonts (included the CSS in `<head>` section). On every other browser out there, font is rendered OK, except Google Chrome. When I first load up the website in Google Chrome, texts using that custom font are NOT displayed AT ALL (even tho font-stack has Georgia as a fallback - `"Roboto Slab", Georgia, serif;`). After I hover the styled link, or retrigger any CSS property in Inspector - texts become visible.

Since I've started the theme some time ago, I can clearly remember that it was working perfectly before. Is this some known recent Chrome update bug?

**First load**:

[image]

**After I reapply any of the CSS properties, get into responsive view or hover an element**:

[image]

Anyone have similar issues? How should I proceed with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the page loading timeline, is your font being fetched properly?

Comment: Have you tried a cache flush? (ctrl+f5)
This sometimes happens too if you don't add "http://" to your font link.

Comment: Hey, yup, fonts are fetching OK. CTRL+F5 is no help, since I've checked it on few different desktops.

For now, I've managed to solve this by binding custom jQuery `redraw()` function, on the element which should have this font applied. It works, but I still wonder why it ain't working without hacks like this.

Comment: Are people still experiencing this problem? I used to but it seems Google have fixed it?

Comment: does this question also apply to Chrome on an Android device?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Apparently it's a [known Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476#c40). There's a css-only workaround that should solve the problem:

```
body {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

It seems like Chrome just needs to be told to repaint the text

Comment: My most recent web project ran into this and it was driving me crazy, thanks so much!

Comment: Hmm, other people in the bug forum were able to get it working using jquery (I wasn't able to though): 
jQuery('body')
   .delay(500)
   .queue( 
    function(next){ 
      jQuery(this).css('padding-right', '1px'); 
    }
   );

Comment: I think this worked for me in OS X, but I don't think it did work in Chrome for Windows :(

Comment: According to the Chromium bug page, the issue has been verified as "fixed' in the latest version of Chrome Canary, so a full fix can't be long now :)

Comment: This has been seriously bugging me!

Comment: An anonymous user also suggested that if this doesn't work, it may help to make the delay loner.

Comment: This is not working for me as well. Adding the delay may not solve it as weel then.

Comment: This worked perfect. For me, this CSS is a better alternative to a javascript workaround. But if this doesn't work for you, try jQuery(function() { jQuery('body').hide().show(); });

Comment: @b1nary what version of Chrome are you using? According to the bug report this issue was fixed in Chrome 34, in April 2014. You may be having a separate problem?

Comment: @Meg 41.0.2272.89, not the newest but definitly newer than that.

Answer (score 11):

## If the css fix does not work for you

In case the [first rated post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22025804/4262057) is not working, here is a solution:

**remove the 'http:' in:**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

or

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One);
```

As explained by [David Bain](http://blog.dbain.com/2012/12/google-web-fonts-not-showing-in-google.html), most modern browsers don't actually require that you specify the protocol, they will "deduce" the protocol based on the context from which you called it

Comment: THIS.  All these sill JS and CSS hacks, when all you need to do is delete "http:"

Comment: same never had it, still the issue.

Comment: This is a valid answer only if your site is running https, because you're trying to pull from a http resource, which the browser won't allow.

Answer (score 9):

The CSS fix didn't work for me, also the 0.5 sec delay script seems awkward.

This JS snippet seems to work for us:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    if (/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        $('body').css('opacity', '1.0') 
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: This only fixes it intermittently for me, wish I could retract my upvote.

Comment: @KarlGlaser You can. Click again on the 'up' to revert to neutral. (Clicking 'down' skips to downvote).

Comment: @OJFord It has to be edited if the grace period is over

Answer (score 7):

Tried the css fix alone above with no success. Finally resolved by creating a style sheet (chrome.css) containing:

```
body {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
 -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
 from { opacity: 1; }
 to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

And loading it with jquery at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('head').append('<link href="/chrome.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: In spite of the fact that this was rated below the accepted answer this solution was on the only one which worked for me.

Comment: This gives an error: `GET https://<insert domain name here>/chrome.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

Comment: The Javascript code fixed the rendering issue!

Answer (score 2):

I've incorporated the above CSS ... but I ALSO am including the following javascript in my header:

(Note, I know I haven't customized the fonts in the code below. But regardless, it still seems to help in forcing Chrome to repaint the fonts on the page ... just make sure your fonts are properly referenced elsewhere)

With the CSS mentioned above used in conjunction with the below code included in my  ... at worst, all fonts on my page will show up after a second or so of delay.

Hope this helps people. Cheers.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

 $(function() { $('body').hide().show(); });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

//JavaScript goes here


WebFontConfig = {
  google: { families: ['FontOne', 'FontTwo'] },
    fontinactive: function (fontFamily, fontDescription) {
   //Something went wrong! Let's load our local fonts.
    WebFontConfig = {
      custom: { families: ['FontOne', 'FontTwo'],
      urls: ['font-one.css', 'font-two.css']
    }
  };
  loadFonts();
  }
};

function loadFonts() {
  var wf = document.createElement('script');
  wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
    '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
  wf.type = 'text/javascript';
  wf.async = 'true';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
}

(function () {
  //Once document is ready, load the fonts.
  loadFonts();
  })();

</script>
```

Here's where I found the above:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/tYHSqc-fqso

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed with the JS solution, but also needed to use the latest google hosted jquery (1.11) to get it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue. I it was due to HTTP/S protocol mismatch as described [here](http://blog.dbain.com/2012/12/google-web-fonts-not-showing-in-google.html).

Use **https** version of URL.

Answer (score 1):

See similar problem in question [Strange Issue while Google Font Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568591/strange-issue-while-google-font-rendering).

Solution is in loading the desired font (I my case 'Fira Sans') from the Mozilla CDN instead of Google CDN.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a actual solution but it works better for me than everything else in this thread. I changed the font. I had *Fira Sans* and now just changed to *Roboto* which works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

i just used to delete roboto font from my windows fonts and every thing work right now.

it is maybe beacause you have older version of font on your system . i guess .

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to work with Meg's answer,but like many others it didn't work for me either.

For using Google Font,found this trick[Adding Screenshots for steps].

1) Just take the url from the css or standard link as highlighted.

2) Open the link in another tab, copy whole css code(i.e. font-face) in your css file and run.

Not sure about performance as many http calls are getting added, or just try copying one font-face.

Image for step 1
[image]

Image for step 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the element has `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` set which can cause this, or similar, issues.  Changing it to `auto` fixed this problem for me with a Foundation 5 project that sets it to `optimizeLegibility` by default.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still struggling with this issue (2019), there seems to be a bug in Google Fonts CSS generator script.

I loaded my fonts with the following tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300">
```

Every `@font-face` in the file contained a line like this:

```
src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), local('sans-serif'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v19/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');
```

As you can see, the `local('sans-serif')` is placed prior to the remote URL, which is wrong. This causes Chrome to load the default sans-serif font instead of the requested one.

A simple fix is to reorder the `font-weight` part of the URL, from `Roboto:400,300` to `Roboto:300,400`. This causes the generator to not include the `local('sans-serif')` source.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just sharing what worked *for me*. Your results may vary.

I had `main.css` with an `@import` of multiple fonts, separated by a `|` (pipe) character. This had been working up until today. I kept all of my Google Font imports in the main CSS file because I didn't have that many. Today I added one that simply wouldn't render, either in Chrome or Firefox. I tried a different font - same problem.

Finally, I made a separate `@import` in another CSS file that gets loaded for several pages on the site (let's call it `navbar_pages.css`, for example) - this CSS gets included in the relevant pages via `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/navbar_pages.css">`, just like `main.css` does.

**For some reason, having the @import in a separate CSS file solved the problem.**

I *suspect* it is due to a limit on the number of fonts that can be called in a single `@import` call. More testing should be done to pin down the cause, but for now there is my workaround. If anyone has insights, please chime in with a comment.

Answer (score -1):

It may not be a silver bullet, but fixe the issue on our site by moving the fontawesome css link to the bottom of our pages as well as weblike fix listed above.

Answer (score -1):

If people are still having this problem before you try all the great solutions on here try using an !important tag in your css to see if that will fix it, as it did for me and I am not sure if the bug is the same as the old Chrome bug.

```
.faultyText {"Roboto Slab", Georgia, serif !important}
```

Answer (score -3):

Checkout plugin I made: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fontfix/ekgfbmjaehhpbakdbpfmlepngjkaalok

It does the web realign with pure javascript, which force browser to redraw whole page.

Comment: We expect the fix to be global, not only to user that installed a custom plugin.