# Body Font Sometimes Disappears

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm having a strange problem where my body fonts sometimes disappears in Chrome on a PC. I will go to the site and it's just gone. I'll refresh and it's still gone, but if I go to another page the body will be there. If I then go back home, the font is back. But if I refresh again it's gone.

I have no idea where to begin troubleshooting this.

I'm using a google web font, roboto. I'm using it on another site with no issue. I've also loaded another google font, and that appears just fine.

Other Info: This is a wordpress site and I'm loading the font in the header.php. Using this code:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Here's the site: http://trinidadpena.com/testing/carriepink/

Basically, I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Fonts are not rendering on Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solves!

[Google Fonts are not rendering on Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome)

I'm sorry, I did search before I posted but I didn't find this answer. Thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I checked in the console and I saw this:

**"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://trinidadpena.com/testing/carriepink/style.css"**

This is probably the problem. Fix the path to the `CSS stylesheet` and check it again.

Comment: Line 119: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen">`

Comment: Hmm... It should be linking to the child theme's style sheet. I'm not sure why it's trying to find it there. All the the other styles are rendering. I'll have to do some digging and see why it's pointing there.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I checked my source and it seems to be linking to the proper style sheet. <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://trinidadpena.com/testing/carriepink/wp-content/themes/Builder-Carrie-Pink-Custom/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />