# Chrome not showing google webfonts

Tags: css, google-chrome

I originally loaded my fonts from google, but then decided to host them locally and still no luck. Here is what my CSS looks like for my fonts

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sans_condensedbold';
    src: url('/campfiles/c9/fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/campfiles/c9/fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/campfiles/c9/fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.svg#open_sans_condensedbold') format('svg'),
         url('/campfiles/c9/fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/campfiles/c9/fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/campfiles/c9/fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.svg#open_sans_condensedbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'materegular';
    src: url('/campfiles/c9/fonts/mate-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/campfiles/c9/fonts/mate-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/campfiles/c9/fonts/mate-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/campfiles/c9/fonts/mate-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/campfiles/c9/fonts/mate-regular-webfont.svg#materegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

When I load my page the text does not appear at all. Though strangely if I right click ->inspect element the text appears. Very bizarre. I read that its a chrome issue that was fixed in Chrome v.33 but I am up to date. Any help would be much appreciate thanks.

Comment: What was the problem when you used the ones from Googles CDN?

Comment: We'd need to see it live. Do you have a link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Fonts are not rendering on Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome)

Comment: When I used Googles CDN got same issue, fonts wouldnt show but if i inspected element or even just refreshed the page it showed, very odd

Comment: This is happening for me too on a site and only in Chrome 33. I wonder if the Chrome 33 release to fix the Typekit web fonts issue has broken Google web fonts.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it hasn't yet been fixed. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome/22025804#22025804), the accepted answer should help (copied here as well):

Apparently it's a known Chrome bug. There's a css-only workaround that should solve the problem (change the p selector to select whatever text elements you use on the site):

```
body {
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
-webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
from { opacity: 1; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

It seems like Chrome just needs to be told to repaint the text

Answer (score -2):

Did you specify the font for any selector?

Try

```
body {
 font-family: 'materegular';
}
```