# Google Webfont acting weird on Chrome

Tags: android, css, wordpress, google-chrome, google-webfonts

I'm using Google Webfont Roboto and Yanone on my Wordpress blog. I'm using WP enqueue to load the fonts:

```
wp_register_style( 'google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500|Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,700', array(), null );
wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts' );
```

Now the strange behavior is as follows:

The font loads (I can see that on my dev tools). But it doesn't show.

1. When I hover on the Yanone font, it shows up mysteriously.
2. When I hover on the Roboto font, it doesn't show up. But when I right click on it, It shows up.
3. Also, if I open the dev tools/inspect element, the font shows up.
4. There's no way to show the fonts on Chrome for Android.

It works fine in all browsers except Google Chrome. (both on Windows and Android phone)
Strangely, it was working fine with Chrome too but suddenly it stopped working. (probably after Chrome updated)

I'm racking my brains apart with the issue. Nothing seems to fix it. Shame that Google can't render its own fonts properly while Firefox etc. has no problem.

Can someone please help me with a workaround? I'm stuck. :(

**p.s. I'm using W3 Total Cache plugin. Just FYI.**

Comment: Can we see a link, please?

Comment: Yea, would be really nice...

Comment: Have you tried disabling W3 Total Cache and refreshing your pages? That plugin, while fantastic, can result in some pretty strange styling if you try and make changes while it's running.

Comment: It looks like a known Chrome bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome but the workaround mentioned doesn't seem to work for me. I've tried disabling W3TC, still the same.