# Chrome bug on special fonts?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, debugging, webfonts

When I load [this](http://tommcfarlin.com/adding-confirmable-to-users-in-devise/) web page in Chrome v33.x, I can't see the fonts, as you can see on this capture.

[image]

But if I re-load the page, then I can see it normally.

[image]

This issue is also in my personal web pages. It doesn't happen on Mozilla, Opera or Safari. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome/22025804?noredirect=1#comment33517893_22025804

Comment: Did you solve this using the referred question?