# Google Chrome: Stylesheet only appears after "Inspect Element"

Tags: asp.net, css, google-chrome, webfonts

I'm experiencing this weird stylesheet problem (only happens in chrome) where the text are only showing after I used the Inspect Element function of the chrome. (Id like to post some images of the error but It seems that I do not have enough reputation points to do so since I am new here)

I've been searching around for quite some time now and still no luck.

Comment: You could place the image on [imgur](http://imgur.com/) then link to it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem: Here's a picture of what I get: http://imgur.com/a97XGXm

I think the problem is with fonts not loading. Images, CSS, and HTML all look good but the fonts may not be there and aren't falling back to alternates. 

Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m under Windows Vista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's an issue with Chrome-based browsers and custom fonts.

See [Google Fonts are not rendering on Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome/22025804) for discussion and answers.

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/22637615/949055 to work in initial testing.

Comment: Never to late to say Thanks! @kenneth, It was indeed the fonts that was causing the problem. Cheers!