# How apache/php treats custom fonts?

Tags: fonts, google-webfonts

I'm not so sure if the fonts that being rendered in web pages have relation in the fonts installed in the server. I'm using custom fonts tru "font-face". But the thing is, it always gives "blocks out" behavior when it being rendered. It seems to be hallow, and after seconds it will be in normal. Sometimes it will just be hallow forever until you hover on it. Then when I looked up on the developers console, it says: 'OTS Derivative Glyphs'. Some of the case, it will say the font that I'm expecting but it is still hallow.

So my questions are:

1. How the apache/php thing treats the font-face? or it is in the client's browser?
2. If I installed locally the fonts(.ttf/.fon) of the web fonts I used it will make sense?
3. How to solve that "hallow" behavior thing of the chrome?

Comment: Firstly, I'm not sure what you mean by "hallow"; perhaps this is a mistranslation from another language? Secondly, like all CSS, @font-face declarations are processed by the browser, not the server; the server just has to serve the files like it would images.

Comment: Ah. I got it now. Btw, by "hallow", I mean it seems to be there but not there..like a transparent object, have shapes but invisible. And I solved it using this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome :)

Comment: Ah, perhaps you were thinking of "hollow", although that makes me picture each letter appearing as an outline, but still readable. I suspect you actually meant it's invisible but takes up space, which isn't quite the same.