# Why is my website navigation disappearing in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-chrome, navigationbar

I created a wordpress website using the theme Photo from wpexplorer. Everything looks great in Firefox and Explorer, but when viewed in Chrome, the website navigation disappears (sometimes). Sometimes it loads just fine. But upon reload, the navigation disappears. How can I fix this problem for viewing the website in Chrome. http://testhouseforgovernor.com

Comment: i tested this in chrome and could not replicate your problem

Comment: I cant find any error.

Comment: It is happening on the site http://www.testhouseforgovernor.com and also on the live site at http:www.houseforgovernor.com it is happening for me and for other users who brought the problem to my attention.

Comment: I believe its any plugin which is slowing the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug for Chrome. Its become most prominent within Chrome 32 and there are still some issues within Chrome 33.

Read more [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476#c40)

There is one suggested fix out there:

```
body {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

It just tells Chrome to re-load the font's opacity which is where the problem lies.

Details from previous SA question found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome)