# AngularJS odd behaviour with model in view

Tags: angularjs

I am having some pretty odd behaviour with some model/view data in Angular. It is two issues really. In my controller, I have the following code, which is used to update some dates in the view.

```
$scope.setCurrentDates = function () {

                var centreIndex = $scope.state.indexOfCentreDate,
                    centreIndexItem = $scope.state.allDays[centreIndex],
                    itemLeft = $scope.state.allDays[centreIndex - 1],
                    itemRight = $scope.state.allDays[centreIndex + 1];

                $timeout(function () {

                    $scope.state.currentDates.centre =  $scope.state.allDays[centreIndex].isoStringdate;
                    $scope.state.currentDates.left = itemLeft.isoStringdate;
                    $scope.state.currentDates.right = itemRight.isoStringdate;

                    $scope.state.isUpdatingDate = false;

                });
            };
```

And then in my view, I have the following as a right/progress nav arrow:

```
    <a>
        <span class="day">{{state.currentDates.right | navDate : 'dd'}}</span>
        <span class="month">{{state.currentDates.right | navDate : 'MMM'}}</span>
        <span class="year">{{state.currentDates.right  | navDate : 'yyyy' }}</span>

    </a>
```

$scope.setCurrentDates in the controller gets called with every click of the above nav.

So, the first issue is as follows:

When first loading the page, no text for the dates displays. However, when I inspect the element in dev tools, and for example increase the font size from 50px to 51px, the text then displays. As I click through the nav, the dates then do not update as they should in the view. **BUT** when I inspect the element again, and decrease the font size back to 50px, the dates then update ??? Bizarre. This happens with any one of the CSS properties for this element I modify.

They then update as they should with each click, but then stop updating again until I modify the CSS again.

At first I though this was a scope issue but I am not so sure as the dates update correctly when logged out in the console. So it must be related to Chrome/CSS rendering.

Further bizarreness is as per the attached. You can see the dev tools DOM, representing the correct values, including within the element `#console` which is represented by the black box rendered on screen.

[image]

It actually looks like this may be isolated to Chrome.

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Strange. A jsfiddle would help. Also, I notice you are calling `$timeout` but without any delay, which is immediate invocation. Why? And is the `navDate` filter defined somewhere?

Comment: Thanks. I have just set it up in a standalone environment and it seems to be working, so i must be getting mangled elsewhere.

Comment: So the jsfiddle works but not in the env?

Comment: Yeah, however, I have had to fake it quite a bit. Unfortunately to post everything in a jsFiddle and replicate exactly, I would need to add my whole module, as it consists of several elements that all come together. I will strip parts out bit by bit as part of a troubleshooting process.

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, can you try to add `$scope.$apply();` at the end of your function (right after the `$timeout`)?

Comment: $timeout uses/calls $apply as far as I am aware, which is why I have excluded it. I have tried both though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the Chrome rendering issue was found here: [Google Fonts are not rendering on Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome/22025804#22025804).

It comes down to Chrome being told to re-render the fonts.