# Strange Issue while Google Font Rendering

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

So I am using the fonts this way

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:700|Open+Sans&text=1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%20' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<style>h1, h2, h3 {font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif; line-height:1.125em} </style>
```

This is the result... 
[image]

**I am completely confused** as how this can even happen? What am I doing wrong. The issue seems only on the  home computer. Rest everywhere I checked its fine.

Home PC: Firefox, Windows 7 (In chrome the fonts are not displaying at all, its blank)

Comment: Do you have a live project we can test?

Comment: http://stylegirl.in @BramVanroy

Comment: have you tried highlighting/copying the "bad" text on the home computer and copy/pasting it elsewhere? If the missing chars show up in the copy/pasted text, then it's a display issue.

Comment: What is with the `text=1234...` querystring in that CSS link?  Why not just pull back the whole font library?  Try removing everything from the `&` to the end of the link to see if that helps.

Comment: @JoshBurgess but if its that issue then it will be in all places not in one scenario....

Comment: Works fine on Chrome, FF and IE on my Surface Pro 3.

Comment: @BramVanroy Same for me... I am baffled... How can only my home PC cause this issue ?

Comment: Post *sufficient* code (HTML and CSS) that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: @DebajyotiDas can you post the specs of your home PC, e.g. CPU, GPU, etc.?

Comment: See also on Google’s GitHub: [FiraSans and FiraMono appear blank](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/10)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using Mozilla's CDN instead of Google's; the latter seems to be buggy with regards to the Fira Sans font.

Replace your `googleapis.com` link with this one and it should work:

`<link href='https://code.cdn.mozilla.net/fonts/fira.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />`

You might have to still use Google's CDN for Open Sans, in addition to Mozilla's for Fira Sans, but Open Sans doesn't seem to have this issue as far as I am aware of.

Comment: Works fine when rendered from Moz

Comment: Is there a way of limiting which weights you bring in?

Comment: I have been using Fira sans for months and I just recently found out that 1 person fails to see the text. I wonder how many visitors in the meantime I have lost because of this... Anyway, how do I test it if it works now?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any custom settings in your GRAPHICS driver config? E.g. is Anisotropic Filtering, Antialiasing / etc. turned on? Firefox tends to pass some of those optimizations through, with bad results :-/

Try turning all of those settings to "Application-controlled" / auto / default whatever and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Not an answer. Should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: The sentence "Try turning all of those settings..." is an answer. It may not be THE answer, but it is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue. The cause was a misconfiguration of the time and date information in my computer. Once I adjusted that, google fonts started to work fine.