# Roboto font in Chrome is not shown properly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, roboto

I've been working for a client site and I have problem with rendering of Roboto font.

In Chrome (ver. 43.0.2357.65 m) all the various weights of Roboto looks same.
Here is the example:
Left is **Mozilla Firefox**, right is **Chrome**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX4Lx.jpg

Do you have any idea what's wrong with it?

thank you

Comment: That doesn't happen to me (Chrome 43.0.2357.81). Does this also happen on the site you are working on? Can you inspect the elements on the google font site and have a look at the "font-family" property?

Comment: It's good here in Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 m

Comment: Are you sure you've loaded all different weights of Roboto font that you're using in your application?

Comment: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900,700,500,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: @VikramDeshmukh oh wow I'm glad for your comment. This was the missing piece.

Comment: @I.R.R. I'm glad it helped! :)

Comment: FYI - I tried using @VikramDeshmukh's snippet, but ran into a `Mixed Content` error in Chrome. Just needed to switch to `https` instead, and it worked fine.

Comment: Good point @lukenetsurfer. FWIW, you can load a the font in an agnostic manner by not mentioning `http:` or `https:` at all. That way, if the page is being served over https it will try to load the font over https.

`<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900,700,500,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it's such a shame, but I have had old version of Roboto installed on my PC.
Since I deleted, everything works fine again.

I should facepalm myself hard..

Comment: Exactly the issue I was facing. Thanks for following up with an answer to your own question!

Answer (score 8):

I have the same version and it's work.

Try to include font in CSS with this code

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic,300italic,300,100italic,100);

body {
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

And set the `font-weight: 300;` for exemple and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Adobe's Creative Cloud and you have Roboto set as a font, you may run into issues where all things in Chrome then get Roboto Bold. I disabled the font from Adobe Fonts and it fixed my issue, but in some Google products like GMAIL, Sans Serif is bolded and you can't turn off the bold. I don't know why and I can't find any good information on how to resolve that.

Comment: This was my issue too, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you use @fontface evert browser use different font format so the complete css is like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

But as suggested using google fonts you should have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I noticed that all periods are square, not circle. Download a fresh copy of [Roboto font here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto-2014) and reinstall it on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, for me what worked was calibrating my monitors and:

1. Go to chrome://flags/
2. Accelerated 2D canvas -> Enable
3. 2D canvas -> Enable  Reboot Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for a Hebrew site, the `font-weight` was set to `900` and the output was showing differently in Firefox and Chrome browsers even though I followed [Google-Font's embedding rules](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) properly:

```
//For example:
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Solution:**
I have just updated the `font-weight` to `700` instead of `900` and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27383566/11417534 fixed this problem for me.

Just delete the protocol declaration (http:// or https://) from the font request.