# Roboto Condensed google font not rendering correctly in Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, google-font-api, roboto

Yesterday a colleague of mine noticed a big inconsistency between the rendering of the google Roboto Condensed font on our site, when displaying on Firefox and Chrome. On Firefox the font doesn't seem to be the same at all.

I did some reading [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911367/roboto-condensed-font-not-rendering-properly-in-mozilla-firefox), but I can't seem to understand if this problem is the same as mine, because the person is using local fonts, and I'm serving directly from google.

Also it seems like somewhere in the wordpress installation, the Roboto Condensed font is being called twice - once imported directly from the theme, once imported by a plugin we're using to customize the menu of the site.

On the other hand, I read that different font weights being used on the same font might produce different results in different browsers, but couldn't grasp what is the right way to use them.

Any help will be appreciated. Here is the site that I'm talking about:
[www.podmosta.bg](http://podmosta.bg)

Best Regards,

Kostadin

Comment: remember to do some checking yourself first: open the dev toolss and check which fonts are actually being used. Chrome is using Robot, but whatever CSS you are using is not kicking in in Firefox: mine reports that it's using Arial, instead. So: what's the CSS you're using? Because it's probably a syntax error that Firefox isn't letting through, but Chrome is, or a network transfer that isn't resolving.

Comment: I had once similar  issue, maybe it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476265/roboto-font-in-chrome-is-not-shown-properly

Comment: I managed to get this right - explained in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved now. 
Turned out that I wasn't loading Roboto Condensed with included cyrillic characters included. Just loaded up the proper version of the font and everything went fine.