# CSS Google Font not showing in certain browsers

Tags: css, browser, fonts

I have a website with Google Fonts. It looks good in a lot of browsers and browser versions, but in some it doesn't show the Google Font. It just replaces it with a standard font from the system.
These systems and browsers don't show the font correctly:
Windows 8.1 firefox 30
Windows XP firefox 40
OS X El Capitan firefox 33
OS X El Capitan safari 9.1
OS X Yosemite chrome 50
OS X Lion firefox 30
Windows 8.1 chrome 40

https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/ac741d87b1968ba566b069a204e8d05bdf37e344

Here is the link to my website: https://unica-schule.ch/wer-sind-wir/geschichte/

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome

Comment: Do some debugging. Is your css declaration being overwritten? Add !important to it. Is there an error in the console? Tell us. Is the font being loaded (network requests) tell us.

Comment: i think this helped. thank you!

Comment: I'd also recommend adding a fallback to your google font declaration, at the very least sans-serif. That way, if it breaks, at least it won't go back to a serif font quite different from Source Sans. A possibly silly suggestion, use single quotes not doubles when calling google fonts; all their examples are this way.