# Stop waiting time out for resources in chrome automation

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, automation

I have automated chrome with Python Selenium Webdriver. Is there any chrome option or method to stop waiting for third party resources ?

When i launched google-chrome in debug mode, it's waiting on below google fonts for 2 minutes.

- https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,500,600,700,800
- https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900

Environment Limitations
 1. No internet
 2. No sudo permission

This is not a rendering issue, browser is waiting on those resources and selenium is giving timeout exception. Need to stop this waiting time and continue automation without errors.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome)

Comment: it's not a rendering issue, browser is waiting on those resources and selenium is giving timeout exception. Need to stop this waiting time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selenium Wire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) has a way of waiting for requests to finish before proceeding with test execution. See https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#waiting-for-a-request